# Use CTE and UNION ALL with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

My problem is that:

Create a view that shows the top 5 selling products as well as an aggregated row that shows the total sales for all other products and a Grand total row that sums all of the above.

```
WITH ProductTop5 AS 
(
    SELECT [dbo].[Product].[ProductName] AS ProductName, SUM([dbo].[SalesOrderDetail].[LineTotal]) AS TotalAmount
    FROM [dbo].[Product]
    JOIN [dbo].[SalesOrderDetail] ON [dbo].[Product].[ProductID] = [dbo].[SalesOrderDetail].[ProductID]
    GROUP BY [dbo].[Product].[ProductName]  
)
```

[image]

Comment: In most cases this should be done in your presentation layer...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER/RANK` to calculate ranking of product:

```
WITH Product AS 
(
    SELECT p.[ProductName] AS ProductName,
           SUM(sod.[LineTotal]) AS TotalAmount
    FROM [dbo].[Product] p
    JOIN [dbo].[SalesOrderDetail] sod 
      ON p.[ProductID] = sod.[ProductID]
    GROUP BY p.[ProductName]  
), ProductWithRank AS (
    SELECT ProductName, Total_Amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Total_Amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM Product
)
SELECT ProductName, TotalAmount
FROM ProductWithRank
WHERE rn <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'All Others', SUM(Total_Amount)
FROM ProductWithRank
WHERE rn > 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', SUM(TotalAmount)
FROM ProductWithRank;
```